# why do these pattern matches overlap?

Tags: haskell

Why do my pattern matches inside a do block overlap?

```
 (q, m) <- newRq
 let m2 = appendMsg "first" key m
     (q4, m4) = case m2 of   
               m -> deleteRec key q m2
               _ -> (q, m2)
```

This compiles with the warning

```
Warning: Pattern match(es) are overlapped
         In a case alternative: _ -> ...
```

and does not work as I want to. It just seems that for (q4, m4) it always returns

```
[], fromList []
```

disregarding what the values of m2 and m are. Is there any local variables where I do not expect them?

What I want to achieve in words: If m2 and m are equal then (q4, m4) should evaluate to `deleteRec key q m2`, otherwise to (q, m2).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first pattern in the `case` (`m`) matches everything and assigns it to `m`. The second one matches everything and discards it (`_`), but has nothing left to match because `m` will get everything.

I think you meant for the case to work like a `switch` statement, but it actually works as a set of patterns, much like a function declaration. So your `case` is the same as something like:

```
check m2
  where check m = deleteRec key q m2
        check _ = (q, m2)
```

In this code, you're probably best off just using an `if`:

```
if m == m2 then deleteRec key q m2 else (q, m2)
```

You might also consider indenting the `if` statement differently:

```
if   m == m2
then deleteRec key q m2
else (q, m2)
```

should also work.

However, in general, you can actually use guards in a `case` statement, so this would work too:

```
case m2 of
  val | m2 == m   -> deleteRec key q m2
      | otherwise -> (q, m2)
```

This is obviously harder to read than an `if`, but if you had more branches or needed to do some actual pattern matching, it would make sense.

Comment: True for the if, but I just was sitting for one hour to avoid it since I always read that it is not idiomatic and that in Haskell developers should use pattern matching wherever possible.

Comment: Yes, you *should* use pattern matching whenever possible. But it is not possible to match against the *value* of a variable. A variable in a pattern is just a "hole" like `_` that can take anything; it then assigns whatever was there to that name.

Comment: Is there still any alternative to if-then-else?

Comment: Well, you could use guards the way I have, but that's harder to read in this case. This is one of the times when an `if then else` statement probably makes the most sense.

Comment: You can indent the `if` statement differently if you want though.

Comment: In the `case` example, I would have used `val` instead of `m2` in the guard and the body, since that's what you would have *had* to do if you were extracting a value (and it gives `val` a raison d'être).  However, I agree that an `if then else` would be better.

Comment: @pat: You have a point. I just translated his code directly; in actual practice, you would want to use the pattern-matched variable.