# Pattern matching with integer in haskell gives wrong result

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I noticed that trying to perform pattern matching in haskell with the arguments doesn't quite always work. Here's an example:

```
test :: Integer -> Integer -> String
test num1 num2 = case num1 of
                    num2 -> "foo"
                    otherwise -> "bar"
```

When I load this in the interpreter, it warns me of overlapping pattern matches. Further more, `test a b` for any two integers `a` and `b` returns `"foo"`, regardless of whether they're equal or not. It appears that the `num2` in the pattern match is not the same as the one in the arguments.

I want to know why exactly this is happening. I'd really appreciate any insight into the situation.

Comment: You pretty much said exactly why it's happening: "the `num2` in the pattern match is not the same as the one in the arguments".

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336385/why-do-these-pattern-matches-overlap

Answer (score 2):

`num2` is a pattern that matches any value. Always. It has nothing to do with an existing variable `num2` that is in scope. (In the right-hand side of the case alternative, here `"foo"`, the value matched will be bound to the name `num2`, shadowing the existing name `num2`. But that's not relevant here since you don't use `num2` anyways.)

Imagine if all your `map f (x : xs) = f x : map f xs` pattern matches changed meaning just because someone defined a top-level variable called `x`!

Similarly, `otherwise` is a pattern that matches everything, and has nothing to do with the top-level value `otherwise`. `otherwise` is supposed to be used in guards like `| otherwise = ...`; its definition is `otherwise = True`.

In this case, the easiest way to fix your program is just

```
test num1 num2 = if num1 == num2 then "foo" else "bar"
```

Comment: What do you mean "has nothing to do with the top-level value `otherwise`"? `otherwise` *is* a top-level value defined in `Prelude`. You can hide it: `import Prelude hiding (otherwise)`. Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: @user3237465 In a pattern match, `otherwise` isn't referring to the value `True`. How could it? You can't match num2, a number, with `True`. Rather, it acts similarly to the `otherwise` defined to be `True`, in that it matches anything: because it is a pattern that never fails to match. Instead of `otherwise` you could equally write `_` or `batman`.

Comment: @amalloy, ah, I overlooked that `otherwise` in the question.